# In DB2 SQL, is it possible to set a variable in the SELECT statement to use multiple times..?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

In DB2 SQL, is it possible to `SET` a variable with the contents of a returned field in the `SELECT` statement, to use multiple times for calculated fields and criteria further along in the same `SELECT` statement?

The purpose is to shrink and streamline the code, by doing a calculation once at the beginning and using it multiple times later on...including the `HAVING`, `WHERE`, and `ORDER BY`.

To be honest, I'm not sure this is possible in any version of SQL, much less DB2.

This is on an IBM iSeries 8202 with DB2 SQL v6, which unfortunately is not a candidate for upgrade at this time. This is a very old & messy database, which I have no control over. I must regularly include "cleanup functions" in my SQL.

To to clarify the question, note the following pseudocode. Actual working code follows further below.

```
DECLARE smnum INTEGER --Not sure if this is correct.
SELECT
-- This is where I'm not sure what to do.
SET CAST((CASE WHEN %smnum%='' THEN '0' ELSE %smnum% END) AS INTEGER) INTO smnum, 
%smnum% AS sm,
invdat, 
invno, 
daqty, 
dapric,
dacost,  
(dapric-dacost)*daqty AS profit
FROM 
saleshistory
WHERE 
%smNum% = 30
ORDER BY
%smnum%
```

Below is my actual working SQL. When adjusted for 2017 or 2016, it can return >10K rows, depending on the salesperson. The complete table has >22M rows.

That buttload of `CASE((CAST...` function is what I wish to replace with a variable. This is not the only example of this. If I can make it work, I have many other queries that could benefit from the technique.

```
SELECT

CAST((CASE WHEN TRIM(DASM#)='' THEN '0' ELSE TRIM(DASM#) END) AS INTEGER) AS DASM,
DAIDAT,
DAINV# AS DAINV,
DALIN# AS DALIN,
CAST(TRIM(DAITEM) AS INTEGER) AS DAITEM,
TRIM(DABSW) AS DABSW,
TRIM(DAPCLS) AS DAPCLS,
DAQTY,
DAPRIC,
DAICOS,
DADPAL,
(DAPRIC-DAICOS+DADPAL)*DAQTY AS PROFIT

FROM

VIPDTAB.DAILYV

WHERE

CAST((CASE WHEN TRIM(DASM#)='' THEN '0' ELSE TRIM(DASM#) END) AS INTEGER)=30 AND
TRIM(DABSW)='B' AND
DAIDAT BETWEEN (YEAR(CURDATE())*10000) AND (((YEAR(CURDATE())+1)*10000)-1) AND 
CAST(TRIM(DACOMP) AS INTEGER)=1

ORDER BY

CAST((CASE WHEN TRIM(DASM#)='' THEN '0' ELSE TRIM(DASM#) END) AS INTEGER),
DAIDAT,
DAINV#,
DALIN#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your SQL would look like with the sub-query that Gordon suggested:

```
SELECT

DASM,
DAIDAT,
DAINV# AS DAINV,
DALIN# AS DALIN,
CAST(DAITEM AS INTEGER) AS DAITEM,
TRIM(DABSW) AS DABSW,
TRIM(DAPCLS) AS DAPCLS,
DAQTY,
DAPRIC,
DAICOS,
DADPAL,
(DAPRIC-DAICOS+DADPAL)*DAQTY AS PROFIT

FROM

(SELECT 
   D.*, 
   CAST((CASE WHEN D.DASM#='' THEN '0' ELSE D.DASM# END) AS INTEGER) AS DASM
   FROM VIPDTAB.DAILYV D
) D

WHERE

DASM=30 AND
TRIM(DABSW)='B' AND
DAIDAT BETWEEN (YEAR(CURDATE())*10000) AND (((YEAR(CURDATE())+1)*10000)-1) AND 
CAST(DACOMP AS INTEGER)=1

ORDER BY

DASM,
DAIDAT,
DAINV#,
DALIN#
```

Notice that I removed a lot of the `trim()` functions, and you could likely remove the rest. The way IBM resolves the Varchar vs. Char comparison thing is by ignoring trailing blanks. So `trim(anything) = ''` is the same as `anything = ''`. And since `cast('   123   ' as integer)` = `123`, I have removed trims from within the cast functions as well. In addition `trim(dabsw) = 'B'` is the same as `dabsw = 'B'` as long as the `'B'` is the first character in `dabsw`. So you could even remove that trim if all you are concerned with is trailing blanks.

Here are some additional notes based on comments. The above paragraph is not talking about auto-trim. Fixed length fields will always return as fixed length fields, the trailing blanks will remain. But in comparisons and expressions where trailing blanks are unimportant, or even a hindrance, they are ignored. In expressions where trailing blanks are important, like concatenation, the trailing blanks are not ignored. Another thing, `trim()` removes both leading and trailing blanks. If you are using `trim()` to read a fixed length character field into a `Varchar`, then `rtrim()` is likely the better choice as it only removes the trailing blanks.

Also, I didn't go through your fields to make sure I got everything you need, I just used `*` in the sub-query. For performance, it would be best to only return the fields you need. So if you replace `D.*` with an actual field list, you can remove the correlation name in the from clause of the sub-query. But, the sub-query itself still needs a correlation clause.

My verification was done using IBM i v7.1.

Comment: Ok, wow, I think I understand this join technique, but it'll take me a bit of staring at it to absorb it. Also, sorry to contradict, but it seems this DB2 system isn't automatically trimming as you explain. I just did a quick test through my "IDE" (aka Access 2007), and also directly through the IBM System i Navigator SQL script window. In both cases, `SELECT DASM# FROM VIPDTAB.DAILYV` did not trim the trailing spaces. But...that's ok, I can keep the trim in the 'CASE' function.

Comment: You are right, it does not convert Char to Varchar, but in comparisons, it ignores trailing blanks, even between varchars! so `values (case when '' = '   ' then 'true' else 'false' end)` returns true.

Comment: I should add that my work includes a combination of native Access 2007 Select queries, but also I do some Pass-Through queries in native DB2 SQL when the functions or size of data causes Access to choke on too much data.

Comment: Ahh ok I get it now. It will still return the blanks, but ignores them in comparisons.

Comment: And in expressions.

Comment: Some expressions. In places where trailing blanks are important like concatenation, they are not ignored.

Comment: Follwup question: I'm concerned about the `D.*` in your code example. Can/should I replace that with only the fields I need? I ask because the DAILYV table is >22M rows and >120 columns. I wonder if  `D.*` might pull too much data and slow things down.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can remove the alias from `DAILYV`, but you still need it on the subquery.

Comment: Omg. I've just had a major realization. I was about to ask if I could convert the subquery to a join. Then I got one of those "this seems familiar" blank stares. Early in this project I created a series of "foundation queries" in Access, and these had all the `TRIM` and `CLNG` for cleanup. But then I started with PassThrough queries direct to DB2 because sometimes they would pull too much data and run the calculations locally...and so very slowly. But...I just realized - I think - all I need to do is convert my foundation queries to PassThrough. I'll have to study this and try it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a subquery or CTE.  I can't figure out the actual logic you want, but the structure looks like this:

```
select . . .
from (select d.*, 
             (CASE . . . END) as calc_field
      from VIPDTAB.DAILYV d
     ) d
```

No variable declaration is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. Can I move the subquery up into the `SELECT`..? I need it to be there so I can use the variable in calculated fields.

Comment: @spinjector . . . I don't understand the comment.  You can use `calc_field` in the outer query as much as you like.

Comment: Ahh ok I see..I think. I'll have to study & test with it. I'm not sure my version of DB2 supports this. I found this article which explains the CTE. But this seems like it complicates matters more than simplifies. But it's interesting learning nonetheless... https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Comment: DB2 for i v6.1 supports CTE's. I have been using them at least since v5.4.

Comment: or select * from (the query) as a order by dasm  I like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsalate the case statement in a view.  I even have the fancy profit calc in there for you to order by profit.  Now the biggest issue you have is the CCSID on the view for calculated columns but that's another question.

```
create or replace view VIPDTAB.DAILYVQ  as 

SELECT
CAST((CASE WHEN TRIM(DASM#)='' THEN '0' ELSE TRIM(DASM#) END) AS INTEGER) AS DASM,
DAIDAT,
DAINV# AS DAINV,
DALIN# AS DALIN,
CAST(TRIM(DAITEM) AS INTEGER) AS DAITEM,
TRIM(DABSW) AS DABSW,
TRIM(DAPCLS) AS DAPCLS,
DAQTY,
DAPRIC,
DAICOS,
DADPAL,
(DAPRIC-DAICOS+DADPAL)*DAQTY AS PROFIT

FROM

VIPDTAB.DAILYV
```

now you can

```
select dasm, count(*) from vipdtab.dailyvq where dasm = 0 group by dasm order by dasm
```

or

```
select * from vipdtab.dailyvq order by profit desc
```